# Make Google Chrome's address bar prefer page titles to domain names when offering completions?

Tags: google-chrome, url, autocomplete, awesomebar, address-bar

I've recently switched from Firefox to Chrome, and the thing I miss most from Firefox is the "Awesome Bar" that suggests completions for what I type primarily based on page titles, and then secondarily based on domain names.

Chrome offers both matching URLs and titles, just like like Firefox, but Chrome seems to always prefer a matching domain name over a matching page title or a match to another part of the URL (besides the domain), no matter how many times I pass over the former for the latter.

In fact, Chrome also prefers to suggest a search rather than matching anything other than a domain name.

So is there any hidden preference I can change to tell Chrome that I care more about page titles than domain names?

Example: I want to go to Google Reader, so I press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and begin typing "reader". The URL for google reader is http://www.google.com/reader/view/#overview-page, so the domain name is www.google.com, which does *not* contain the word "reader". So the first option that Chrome suggests is either another site that has "reader" as part of the domain, or a search for "reader" with the default search engine. No matter how many times I scroll down and select Google Reader, Chrome never "learns" that that's what I want.

Comment: could you update with a specific example? It'd help me understand

Comment: Excuse me for saying that, but http://reader.google.com would take you to Google Reader by typing "reader" (or, "r", that is). This applies to many domains, and I have become used to it when switching from firefox.

Comment: Hmm. reader.google.com redirects to google.com/reader. I guess that's a fix for this specific case, but I would still like a general fix.

Comment: I recently switched to Chrome and this is what I am missing a lot. Its actually a very significant loss of productivity that I cannot go to a URL by typing a string from the title. I couldn't find any addons to do this too.

Comment: A workaround, adding Chrome history as a search engine - https://superuser.com/a/160649/100311. Works good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no explicit way to do this in Chrome. At some point I did notice a menu in about:flags  that allowed you to configure the behavior of instant (if you use instant from your omnibar) to act a little differently, but that seems to have gone away in more recent updates (I use the developer release on OS X).

Answer (score 1):

There's a feature flag called **#omnibox-autocomplete-titles** you can enable that does exactly this. Go to `chrome://flags/#omnibox-autocomplete-titles` and change the setting from **Default** to **Enabled**.

Answer (score 0):

Guess your best bet is to try [their discussion forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome?hl=en) or get someone to change the source code.

There is no configuration setting or extension that has access to what you are trying to do...