# How to make Chrome/Chromium omnibox autocomplete from history titles?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, chromium

I recently switched back from Firefox to Chromium, but one feature I'm already missing from Firefox is the completion of the address bar. In Firefox, I can type part of the *title* (not URL) of a page I visited previously, and it will dig up the URL for me. This is especially handy for Google Drive documents, whose URLs do not contain anything meaningful; but I would like it to work across the web.

Is there a way to get this awesomeness in Chromium as well?

Comment: That being said, if you don't mind me asking, why are you switching back?

Comment: @Run5k Performance, mostly. Firefox Quantum is faster than the old one, but still not nearly as snappy as Chromium. Also some tabs with heavy web applications (like Slack and Trello) sometimes randomly start consuming an entire CPU core. Also the LastPass extension for Chromium is slightly better, which of course isn't Firefox's fault but still something I care about.

Comment: @Run5k Also switching tabs by scrolling the mouse wheel over the tab bar. There used to be a Firefox extension for that but it doesn't work on Quantum. (Chromium for Windows oddly doesn't have this feature either.)

Comment: Understood.  From my perspective, there are pros & cons on both sides of the fence.  Most of my IT support team prefers Firefox because of the extensive customization options, especially within the `about:config` interface.   Of course, the capability you mentioned within your question is a contributing factor, also!  However, none of us have seen anything similar to the browser *"randomly start consuming an entire CPU core."*

Comment: Actually I think this might be a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/221116/make-google-chromes-address-bar-prefer-page-titles-to-domain-names-when-offerin , although I've never seen Chromium even attempting to complete from page titles, unless the page is bookmarked. And the dupe is 8 years old and lacks a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Google Chrome's address bar prefer page titles to domain names when offering completions?](https://superuser.com/questions/221116/make-google-chromes-address-bar-prefer-page-titles-to-domain-names-when-offerin)

Comment: Hmm, it magically started working. Huh.

Answer (score 2):

As of Chrome version 80, there's a feature flag called **#omnibox-autocomplete-titles** you can enable that does exactly this. Go to `chrome://flags/#omnibox-autocomplete-titles` and change the setting from **Default** to **Enabled**. This flag may be present in earlier versions too. The description states:

> Allows autocompleting bookmark, history, and document suggestions when the user input is a prefix of their titles, as opposed to their URLs.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Unbelievable that Chrome only added this in 2020.
This missing feature is the primary reason I have stayed with Firefox for years.
Thanks for the answer. It works!